# jQuery time picker

Tags: javascript, jquery, time

I'm looking to fill a text input with a time that the user can choose in 15 minute intervals. I know there are a few plugins out there. I was wondering if there was any “industry standard” plugin, or strong objective reasons to prefer a particular one in common scenarios.

Comment: Thanks for all of your answers, they were very helpful!

Comment: Depending on the granularity you need, you could use a slider control. Have a look at kayak.com and how they use sliders in the results page to set the time range. I've used this to effect with a time range, but it could also work well just to set a time.

Answer (score 86, accepted):

I found [this plugin](http://labs.perifer.se/timedatepicker/) ([github repository](https://github.com/perifer/timePicker)) trumps the other one mentioned.  It mimics Google Calendar's timepicker.

Comment: +1 Common sense prevails. I'd happily see the OP change his mind and accept this answer.

Comment: This plugin doesn't handle invalid entries well, at all. If I type in "abc" it becomes "2:00 AM".

Comment: the link from `this plugin` is broken. Could you fix/remove it?

Answer (score 35):

I tried a ton of timepicker and was not satisfied so I wrote [yet] another one. I think it works well. Also it is inspired from the datepicker so it looks like standard jQuery UI stuff.

The default minute increments is at 5 and can be set to 15 in the options.

http://fgelinas.com/code/timepicker

Comment: Nice Francois +1 I looked at demo's and might have a play with this soon!

Comment: I really like Francois plugin.  1) it allows manual typing for @Kev's power users 2) it doesn't require scrolling 3) humans think of time as am/pm then hours and then minutes (increasing levels of specificity), not a continuum of hours and minutes from midnight. This is how Francois presents time to your users.

Comment: To beat the dead horse, time picker plugins that require you to scroll through a list of hours/minutes (1:15, 1:30, 1:45, etc) are exactly the same as a date picker that required you to scroll though one drop down of days/months (1-jan, 2-jan, 3-jan).  I've never seen anyone suggest THAT was a good idea.

Comment: Thanks for creating this plugin - it's the most usable one I've seen and end users have told me they find it very easy to use.

Comment: @Francois I liked your idea and tried using the plugin.  It was improperly rendering the dropdown selection when used in a text box in a modal with an overlay (times appeared behind the overlay).  It might have been a z-index issue with our current CSS, but I haven't had time to look into it.  I would've posted this as an issue on github, but it looks like the issues tab doesn't exist for your project.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to make a jQuery UI friendly time picker.

Comment: this should be added to jquery UI

Answer (score 20):

My advice would be not to do this. I find it bad enough being forced to use a calendar control just to enter a date, especially when not given the option to type a date which I can do way quicker than navigating yet another wacky control.

Time pickers just take this kind of UI fetish to a new extreme. Why not allow your users to either type the time or just use a couple of drop down boxes for hours and mins. Even drop down lists allow a user to just type the time. The time picker in [Shog9's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/476822/jquery-time-picker#476861) is all very nice to look at but is incredibly fiddly to use. If I was an end user having to use a data entry app and it had a control like that on the page then it's only going to slow me down and make me want to come and cut off the developers hands. :)

Think about usability first before how slick the app looks.

Just my humble opinion.

Comment: I'm curious since I was going to use jquery-timepickr myself: The demo at http://code.google.com/p/jquery-utils/wiki/UiTimepickr shows an input field which can be typed into. The timepicker is just an option. would that be a turnoff for your as well?

Comment: If you give both options then I have no problem, just as long you don't force users into having to work their way through a date/time picker when there's a perfectly good textbox they could type the date/time into. This applies especially if this is a page used over and over by the same types of users, such as data entry staff or call centre personnel.

Comment: @Adrian Grigore I don't think this works with the latest build (1.8) of jquery.ui... look at issue 41 for more details.

Comment: -1 because the question is for a timepicker and the accepted answer is "don't". I'm pretty sure there are quite a few plugins that allow manual entry and ui clickness.

Comment: @dotjoe - how about citing one of these examples, and one that doesn't come with a raft of usability issues.

Comment: -1 because when used properly, a timepicker can prevent the user from entering a time in the wrong format, which could create garbage results.  With free-form entry you'd have to validate the input after it's been typed and possibly complain if the input doesn't match the required format.  For best usability, you should prevent bad input rather than complain about it (nobody likes to be told that they've done something wrong), using the least obtrusive method possible.

Comment: @andrew - that's utterly nonsense. have you ever seen high speed data entry staff at work on green screen terminals. No pickers there.

Comment: @Kev, high speed data entry staff are power users who don't need input assistance.  Chain saws used by lumberjacks don't have all of the safety features that consumer models have.  That said, I used to review paychecks that were keyed in by high speed data entry staff, and every batch had at least one paycheck that was completely illegible because the operator had their fingers stationed on the wrong keys and didn't even bother to verify what they were typing.

Comment: @andrew - you cannot seriously be suggesting that time pickers such as the one linked to by Shog provide a better usability experience than just typing in the time and validating using javascript upon exiting the field (I am aware that you can actually type in the time, but what if you couldn't)? That thing is a mess, you're better off with a select list instead of all those wee boxes popping and moving around. It also has some serious accessibility issues as well. Time pickers are just Javascript noodling for the sake of it.

Comment: @Kev, I completely agree that the picker in Shog's answer detracts from usability; like you, I am very frustrated when an interface slows me down instead of improving my productivity.  Drop-down lists for time create a similar delay.  But let's not say that time (or date) pickers are inherently evil. I, for one, am trying to create a picker that guarantees speedy yet correct input from both the keyboard and mouse.  I have the mouse part working, which is a good start, and keyboard accessibility covered, also.  Now it's just a matter of getting the keypress validation worked out!  :)

Answer (score 10):

It's not jQuery ... but I have found that a dropdown, with a list of fifteen minute intervals of time, 8:00AM, 8:15AM, 8:30AM, and so on, is extremely easy for the user to interact with.

Not sure if you **really** need a jQuery way of doing this ... may be overkill. Just an opinion based on my personal experience with **real** users and developing business applications.

Answer (score 8):

If you are interested in using a good time parser and allowing the user to enter in a wide range of valid time strings (8:00 AM, 8AM, 8a, 8, etc), take a look at http://www.datejs.com/.

Here is the jquery code I am using to work with it.

```
$('.time').blur(function (e) {
    var val = $(this).val();
    if (!isNaN(val))
        // add minutes to numeric value otherwise it will be interpreted as a date
        val = val + ':00'; 
    var dt = Date.parse(val);
    $(this).val(dt.toString('h:mm tt'))
});
```

Comment: [Sugar](http://sugarjs.com/) looks like an interesting alternative to DateJS. It has a bunch of date/time methods, but also includes many other JS enhancements.

Answer (score 5):

I think every answer, except Kev's, is subjective. I've seen tenths of time-picker JQuery plug-ins on the net, and most were useless time consuming gimmicks, but if you already use the standard Jquery datepicker then [this plug-in](http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/) would be appropriate.

Comment: -1 for so many reasons I can't count. First - Kev's answer is completely subjective as well. He's just stating an opinion. Second - your answer is completely subjective. Third, that time picker plugin is the only thing I've seen worse from a UI standpoint than the one Shog9 recommended. Finally, your answer should be an answer, not a commentary on other answers. That's what comments are for. I guess I CAN count the problems with the answer - there's four.

Comment: Thanks for the observations. You're right on almost every account :), but I didn't said that the plug-in I recommended is the very best, just that it goes together very well with the JQuery datepicker...maybe I should have formulated it differently.

Answer (score 4):

Check out Maxime Haineault's [jQuery.timepicker](http://haineault.com/media/jquery/ui-timepickr/page/). Pretty cool, IMHO...

Comment: cool but horrible to use

Comment: I would disagree with it being cool and agree with @Espen that it would be horrible to use.

Comment: Any UI data entry widget that changes the value by just moving the mouse over the control is a bad idea.  It makes it way to easy to accidentally change the input value.

Comment: It handles manual input the worse way possible (by ignoring them).

Answer (score 4):

The best I have ever used is the one offered by Telerik.

http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/calendar/examples/datetimepicker/overview/defaultcs.aspx

It is unobtrusive, letting the user just enter in the time or click on the clock icon to select from a list. Basically just a more aesthetically appealing method of using editable drop downs.

Comment: too bad there isn't a version for asp.net mvc

Comment: there is http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/DatePicker

Comment: And I don't work for Telerik. I like some of there stuff, other stuff I loathe. For instance, RadWindow. Bleh.

Comment: am I doing something wrong, or does that timepicker really disallow entering a time between 11:01 p.m. and midnight?

Answer (score 4):

Try this great lib - http://code.google.com/p/mobiscroll/

Demo - http://demo.mobiscroll.com/

Answer (score 3):

Here is my try on the subject:
http://yoka.github.com/jquery-timeselect/

Answer (score 3):

I have been using [Trent Richardson's timepicker library](http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/) and have found it to be great. It is a very popular one too, by number of downloads.

Comment: went through the whole list, this one is the cleanest one out there from a UI perspective IMO -- should be the selected answer. +1

Answer (score 1):

My situation was slightly different, I needed a date time picker but couldn't find one either. So I decided to write one. You can find the [full source here](http://www.yart.com.au//DateTime/TimeCalendar.js); I also posted [a quick demo](http://www.yart.com.au/Resources/ASP-NET/ASP-NET-JQuery-Date-Time-Control.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

[I wrote one](http://github.com/gdoermann/jquery.ui.timepicker) based off of the plugin Jim mentioned (works like google calendar time picker) but it works using jquery ui autocomplete.  It is MUCH more stable than the afore mentioned plugin.  I had issues with that one positioning itself on the page.  The plugin takes an array, time range and intervals or an ajax source... so you can customize it to your hearts content.

Comment: sounds interesting. do you have a demo site for the plugin?

Comment: I don't yet, but I do use it on my site.  You can go to http://snirk.snirk.com/ and click on an unschedule block.  It will bring up a dialog that uses the plugin (the Start Time).

Answer (score 1):

Whilst there isn't a standard one, I've been using a [jQuery plugin from Keith Wood](http://keith-wood.name/timeEntry.html). Unlike some, this degrades to a text box (that you can still type in, whilst still performing validation), and can also be used with a mouse if you're so inclined.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't find a plugin that did what I wanted (i.e., multi-column autocomplete combined with input masking for time), so I wrote [MenuOptions](http://www.menuoptions.org/examples/ReloadMenuOptions.html)

What it looks like
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The [Any+Time™ DatePicker/TimePicker AJAX Calendar Widget](http://www.ama3.com/anytime/) allows time selection which, when using the mouse, is about as fast as typing by hand, but has the added benefit of error prevention.  The time can be formatted any way necessary.  It also supports keyboard manipulation, although admittedly the keyboard access is not as quick as the mouse or typing... but again, it guarantees the value will be in the required format.  It's also easy-to-customize and can handle dates as well.