# Time Input Field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am building a form to accept a time value HH:MM, how can I filter the user input and show the colon in the text field? I guess I'm looking for some kind of filtered input box.

Comment: Filter it how? What's the expected input?

Comment: as far as I can tell, he's asking for an input mask

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thats commonly referred to as an [Input Mask](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Input_mask), do some [googling](http://www.google.com/search?q=jquery+input+mask) on it.  Edit: There appears to be an [input mask jquery plugin](http://www.webappers.com/2008/04/22/jquery-masked-input-plugin/)

Answer (score 3):

Whilst the TimePickr plugin [recommended by Jonathon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1038754/time-input-field/1038789#1038789) is very nice to look at, if the user is doing any volume of data entry, it's going to drive them mad. I answered a similar question a while back explaining why:

> [jQuery time picker (StackOverflow)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/476822/jquery-time-picker/476937#476937)

A [masked input box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1038754/time-input-field/1038797#1038797) and a bit of javascript validation may be a more optimal solution.

Comment: +1 I agree - the "timepickr" isn't a solve-all.

Comment: I loved the look of it but when I played around in a proof of concept for one of our customer thingies I got a bit demented by it :)

Answer (score 1):

Have you ever use JqueryMasked Input Plugin

http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/

Comment: while I like this pluggin very much, it causes some issues with IE 8 in compatibility mode.

Answer (score 0):

The [EZ Time JS widget](http://litusys.info) can do this for you. It takes the bare minimum input and properly formats and validates it. It automatically corrects/removes invalid characters. It is 100% keyboard based and is aimed at high productivity for trained users. It avoids the pitfalls of Javascript 'Time Pickers' that require tedious and slow clicking, dragging, and mouse movements which hamper productivity.

In reference to the above comment, EZ Time JS was developed specifically for serious, heavy loads of data entry and is perfect for scheduling work.

It not only validates but it also automatically removes and/or corrects invalid input. It accepts shortcuts that make entering time very quick.

Here are some examples:

```
INPUT --> OUTPUT
8 --> 08:00 AM
515p --> 05:15 PM
12f --> 12:15 AM --notice the use of shortcut codes, ie., f = 15
```

Since you mentioned colons, with EZ Time you can leave out spaces and the colon for convenience. It adds them back for you in the output.

EZ Time JS makes entering time extremely easy.