# Scan string for special characters and alphabets

Tags: javascript, string

I have a textbox which accepts time (max of 5 chars) in the format hh:mm or hhmm. Pls tell me a way I can just scan the string entered in the textbox, for special characters and alphabets? [If the string entered has these chars or alphabets, then an alert is displayed('Pls enter a valid time')] I tried the str.match and str.indexOf methods but it doesn't seem to help.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    function clocks(){

        var clk = document.getElementById('TIME').value;
        var ampm = document.getElementById('AMPM').value;
var iChars = "!@#$%^&*()+=-[]\\\';,./{}|\":<>?";

  for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    if (iChars.indexOf(clks.charAt(i)) != -1) {
    alert ("Pls enter a valid time");
    return false;
    }
  }



.....}

</script>
```

Comment: are you looking for a solution in Java or JavaScript? could you post your current solution?

Comment: check this post post for javascript time masking:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1038754/time-input-field

Comment: @Vijay : I need a solution in Javascript.

Comment: @Ahmad :Thanks Ahmad. But I cannot make use of any plugins, unfortunately.

Comment: check this javascript library (its only a single javascript file), its simple, small and i guess solves your problem

http://www.pengoworks.com/workshop/js/mask/

P.S. there are many javascripts libs like that, you may find something better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How are you using string.match()?  This should work:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
function clocks(){

    var clk = document.getElementById('TIME').value;
    var ampm = document.getElementById('AMPM').value;

    if (clk.match(/[^0-9:]/)) {
        alert("Please enter a valid time");
    }

    // or, an even more precise regex
    if (!clk.match(/^\d+:\d+$/)) {
        alert("Please enter a valid time");
    }
.....}

</script>
```

The first regex match should check for anything that is NOT a digit or the ':' character, and raise an alert if it finds anything. The second one will match any string that starts with one or more digits, then a ':' character, then one or more digits, then the end of the string (which is the format you're trying to match).

Comment: Thanks so much! I used the first one you mentioned and it works perfectly! Thanks again :D

Comment: Using the `test()` method of the regular expression would be slightly more efficient: `/[^0-9:]/.test(clk)`