# How to validate with Javascript an Input text with Hours and Minutes

Tags: javascript, validation

I have to build an HTML Form with an Input text field for Hours and Minutes.
Something like:

> **Name :**  [Foo]
>   **Surname :** [Bar]
>   **Task :** [Spam]
>   **Hours Minutes :**  [00:15] <-- Input text.

How can I help/validate/force user to compile Hours and Minutes values in the only allowed **HH:mm** format  using Javascript? <sup>*</sup>

Valid time range: from **00:00** to **23:59**

<sup>* I can't use Jquery and of course I will double check the submitted value server side</sup>

Comment: What about having 2 inputs one for hours one for minutes, and then on submit doing what u want with them. (validating then compiling them into whatever format you wish)

Comment: Related question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1038754/time-input-field . Apparently "input mask" seems to be the key.

Answer (score 89, accepted):

Either with the following regular expression :

```
^([0-1]?[0-9]|2[0-4]):([0-5][0-9])(:[0-5][0-9])?$
```

Or by hand, but I strongly suggest the RegExp :)
A simple example :

```js
function validateHhMm(inputField) {
    var isValid = /^([0-1]?[0-9]|2[0-4]):([0-5][0-9])(:[0-5][0-9])?$/.test(inputField.value);

    if (isValid) {
      inputField.style.backgroundColor = '#bfa';
    } else {
      inputField.style.backgroundColor = '#fba';
    }

    return isValid;
  }
```

```html
<input type="text" onchange="validateHhMm(this);" />
```

Comment: Of course you can then manually validate the hour values (hour <= 23) to improve the function, I forgot to add that.

Comment: why not doing it directly with regexp?

Comment: @system
"/^([0-1]?[0-9]|2[0-4]):([0-5][0-9])(:[0-5][0-9])?$/" is an explicit regexp object, and is the same thing as doing new RegExp("...");

Comment: regex not support for this case :  24:00:01

Comment: Make this minor edit to disallow inputs like 24:00:01. Use:
^([0-1]?[0-9]|2[0-3]):([0-5][0-9])(:[0-5][0-9])?$

Answer (score 32):

The RegExp from the first answer doesn't match the OP's query correctly.

```
^([0-1]?[0-9]|2[0-4]):([0-5][0-9])(:[0-5][0-9])?$
```

Should be

```
^([0-1][0-9]|2[0-3]):([0-5][0-9])$
```

Matches 00-19 or 20-23 : 00-59

OP requested validation of HH:MM in the range 00:00 - 23:59

No seconds. 24:00 should not be valid. Double digits for input of hour and minute.

Comment: OP wanted leading 0 24-hour clock yet I needed a 24 hour clock with optional leading 0.  I took your answer as a basis and came up with   ^(|0?[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3]):([0-5][0-9])$

Answer (score 9):

With moment.js the way is:

```
const time = '23:59'
moment(time, 'HH:mm', true).isValid()
```

Comment: Won't moment(time, 'H:mm', true).isValid() be more accurate if the passed time is '3:57'.

Answer (score 8):

```
<HTML>
<Head>
<script language="javascript">
function validateTime(obj)
{
    var timeValue = obj.value;
    if(timeValue == "" || timeValue.indexOf(":")<0)
    {
        alert("Invalid Time format");
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        var sHours = timeValue.split(':')[0];
        var sMinutes = timeValue.split(':')[1];

        if(sHours == "" || isNaN(sHours) || parseInt(sHours)>23)
        {
            alert("Invalid Time format");
            return false;
        }
        else if(parseInt(sHours) == 0)
            sHours = "00";
        else if (sHours <10)
            sHours = "0"+sHours;

        if(sMinutes == "" || isNaN(sMinutes) || parseInt(sMinutes)>59)
        {
            alert("Invalid Time format");
            return false;
        }
        else if(parseInt(sMinutes) == 0)
            sMinutes = "00";
        else if (sMinutes <10)
            sMinutes = "0"+sMinutes;    

        obj.value = sHours + ":" + sMinutes;        
    }

    return true;    
}


</script>
</Head>
<Body>
<input type="text" onblur="validateTime(this)">
</Body>
</HTML>
```

Answer (score 3):

How about

```
function validTime(inputStr) {
    if (!inputStr || inputStr.length<1) {return false;}
    var time = inputStr.split(':');
    return time.length === 2 
           && parseInt(time[0],10)>=0 
           && parseInt(time[0],10)<=23 
           && parseInt(time[1],10)>=0 
           && parseInt(time[1],10)<=59;
}
```

Comment: For this string: "1rrrr2:23" it returns true.     For some reason parseInt for "1rrrr2" is valid.

Comment: Yes, `parseInt("1rrrr2",10)` results in `1`, because the input string begins with a value that can be converted to int. See also: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt

Answer (score 3):

You can use this function to check for time format:

```
function validateTime (time) {
  const timeReg = /^([0-9]|0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]$/
  return time.match(timeReg)
}
```

If you want to have just hour and minute please replace `timeReg` with this:

```
const timeReg = /^([0-9]|0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]$/
```

And this one for the date format:

```
function validateDate (date) {
  try {
    new Date(date).toISOString()
    return true
  } catch (e) {
    return false
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like jQuery.maskedit

Answer (score 0):

might not be the best but this works for me. i am returning false if there is no error in this case. checks for both format and values.

```
if (value.substr(2,1) === ':') {
    if (!value.match(/^\d\d:\d\d/)) {
        return "Invalid Format";
    }
    else if (parseInt(value.substr(0,2)) >= 24 || parseInt(value.substr(3,2)) >= 60)  {
        return "Invalid Format";
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }

}
else {
    return "Invalid Format";
}
```